# Pass parameters in a function through command button

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to pass parameters in a function through command button?

**Method**

```
public PageReference ContactsAdd(String Id){
    campaigns  = [Select id,Name from campaign where Id ='7017F000000TzY1'];
    CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId='7017F000000TzY1', ContactId = + Id , Status = 'Sent');
    members.add(cm);
}
```

**Button**

```
<apex:commandButton value="Add to Campaign!" action="{!ContactsAdd}"> 
       <apex:param name="Id" value='0037F000004yM2m' assignTo="{!Id}"/> 
</apex:commandButton>
```

this gives me error :

> unknown method'AccountStandardController.ContactsAdd()'

Comment: <apex:commandButton  value="Add to Campaign!" action="{!ContactsAdd}">
  
<apex:param name="Id" value='0037F000004yM2m' assignTo="{!Id}"/>

</apex:commandButton>

Comment: Use `apex:param` in command button. Refer [this post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/) by Jeff.

Comment: i have already used apes:param in command button. Also i refer this link but  it is not working

Comment: Suggest you to edit your post and add appropriate details.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass the value to a parameterized method like you are attempting to.

Using a remote action is one way to do it but it really does not add any value for this simple use case.

Remote action would be great if you have to pull values from inputs prior to invoking the method (when they are not set in the controller yet). When using the param the value has to exist / be concrete at the time the button is clicked.

Here are a couple ways to achieve the same goal using the param...

Here are two ways you could do it:

> First way using a property - The assignTo on the param will assign the value to the Property

**Controller Code**

```
public String theId {get;set;} //This is one way - create property to assign to

public PageReference ContactsAdd(String Id){
    campaigns  = [Select id,Name from campaign where Id ='7017F000000TzY1'];
    CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId='7017F000000TzY1', ContactId = theId , Status = 'Sent'); //use your theId here
    members.add(cm);
}
```

**Button**

```
<apex:commandButton value="Add to Campaign!" action="{!ContactsAdd}"> 
       <apex:param name="theId" value='0037F000004yM2m' assignTo="{!theId}"/> 
</apex:commandButton>
```

**Note** I changed the param Name to theId to avoid potential conflicts

> Second way - Grabbing the param from the page - Using the name of the param to get the value

```
public String theId {  
    get{
        return Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('theId');
    }
}

public PageReference ContactsAdd(String Id){
    campaigns  = [Select id,Name from campaign where Id ='7017F000000TzY1'];
    CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId='7017F000000TzY1', ContactId = theId , Status = 'Sent'); //use your theId here
    members.add(cm);
}
```

**Button**

```
<apex:commandButton value="Add to Campaign!" action="{!ContactsAdd}"> 
       <apex:param name="theId" value='0037F000004yM2m'/> 
</apex:commandButton>
```

> Full working example of the second way including how to use merge fields so you do not have to hardcode the value

**Controller**

```
public class myExample{

    public Account acc {get; set;}

    public myExample(){
        acc = New Account(Name = 'abcdef');
    }

    public void doStuff(){
        //Do stuff
    }

    public String theString {  
        get{
            return Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('theString');
        }
    }   
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page id="myExamplePage" controller="myExample">
    <apex:pageMessages id="msgs"/>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!doStuff}" value="Click Me" rerender="thePanel">
            <apex:param value="{!acc.Name}" name="theString"/>
        </apex:commandButton>


        <apex:outputpanel layout="block" id="thePanel">

            {!theString}

        </apex:outputpanel>


    </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Simply load the page, click the button and watch the value of Account Name appear

**NOTE** [The documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm) does not say that the `<apex:param>` can be a direct child of a command button. It works but it is not documented so use at your own peril.

Comment: +1 An underrated answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass value by `<apex:param>` to the Controller method which is expecting parameter with the use of CommandButton action or using any ActionFunctions.

The `assignTo` attribute is basically:

> A setter method that assigns the value of this param to a variable in the associated Visualforce controller. If this attribute is used, getter and setter methods, or a property with get and set values, must be defined.

If you really want to pass parameters to a controller method then use `RemoteAction` (Javascript remoting)

```
[***namespace***.]controller.method(
    [parameters...,]
    callbackFunction,
    [configuration]
);
```

Also, refer [JavaScript Remoting Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm)